# Add Comment Section in View DetailPage

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-core

I am working on Bookevent application I want to add comment section on eventdetail page where I am already using EventViewModel to display information of event detail and I also what to add comment section so user can post the comment.
So basically, My question is how can I use comment model as well on same view page. I searched for it and I found that we can use tuple. But I think that's not good practice in this case. Can Someone suggest any other way please.

CommentViewModel.cs

```
 public class CommentViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string CommentAdded { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int EventId { get; set; }
        
    }
```

EventDetail.cshtml

@model EventViewModel

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h2 class="mt-5 mb-5 text-center">Event Details</h2>
        <div class="table-responsive field ms-5 mt-3">
            <table class="table" id="stu_table">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <td>Title</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <td>Date</td>
                        s
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Location</th>
                        <td>Location</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>StartTime</th>
                        <td>StartTime</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <td>Type</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Duration</th>
                        <td>Duration</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <td>Description</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>OtherDetails</th>
                        <td>OtherDetails</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <form asp-controller="Comment" asp-action="CreateComment">
            <div>   
                <label asp-for="CommentAdded"class="control-label">Add Comment</label>
                <textarea asp-for="CommentAdded"rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
                <input class="btn-btn-default" value="Create" type="submit"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

"I want to add comment section on eventdetail page where I am already using EventViewModel"

Okay, so you have 2 options.

1. Use **ViewBag** or **ViewData[]** to pass the additional data from the controller to the View and then display it, you can still use your EventViewModel as well without changing anything in it.

In this case though you can't use **"asp-for="** for the things you got from the ViewBag/ViewData[].

If you want to send the data back to the controller after submitting the form, use **"name="** and make a parameter in your controller action with the same string name.

2. The method I prefer is to just **put everything that you need for a particular view in its own view model**. If you already have a view model EventViewModel, just add CommentViewModel inside of it (view model that has another view model).

Your code will look like this:

```
        public class EventViewModel
        {
            public CommentViewModel CommentViewModel { get; set; }

            // the usual properties you have for EventViewModel
        }
```